# AWS - Granting access to all resources with specific tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a IAM group that can fully access all resources that have certain tags.

For example, if an S3 bucket and an EC2 instance are tagged `env:qa`, the group `project-qa` should have full access to them.

So far I've tried the following policy:

```json
{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                Effect: "Allow",
                Action: "*",
                Resource: "*",
                Condition: {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "aws:ResourceTag/env": "qa"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I created an account to test this, but when browsing buckets I was immediately told that I lack permissions for the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` action - which I assumed would be covered by `Action: "*"`

Comment: Tag-based permissions don't work on buckets. Only objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `ListAllMyBuckets` action is covered by the `*` but its "resource" is not tagged because its resource is not actually a really existing resource and therefore you are not allowed to perform that operation. You either have `ListAllMyBuckets` for `*` or you don't, there is no way to restrict that based on the bucket, because you are not listing a bucket, you are listing all buckets and this "all buckets" does not have a tag, it does not really have anything, it does not really exist. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html: the `Resource types` for `ListAllMyBuckets` is empty, there is no actual resource to interact with.

Listing object in a bucket can work based on tags, but not listing all the buckets in the first place. Same thing will happen in a lot of places, listing does not respect the permission for the resources that are being listed. Look at it this way: you may not be allowed to do anything with the bucket, you cannot browse it, configure it but you are still allowed to *see* it in the list.

The only way around this is to add these special permission one by one as soon as you see that you are missing one.

---

Note that there are actual AWS resources that are not taggable and therefore you will not succeed with that strategy at all.

Comment: Good Lord, every time I try to do something in AWS that should be simple, I end up wasting hours with nonesense like this.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful with the above policy, you are giving access to destroy resources for example  `route53` **DeleteHostedZone**  and many resources as [@luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207047/2246345) pointed out doesn't follow the tag-based condition at all.

This is a kind of hard-learned lesson for me. Keep this document [AWS services that work with IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) handy while writing policies.

This gives you the idea which service supports what kind of restrictions like:

- Resource-level permissions
- source-based policies
- Authorization based on tags
- Temporary credentials
- Service-linked roles

To be frank, If I were you, I would use selective allow actions which I want as by default in IAM all actions are denied.

Comment: Are you sure you give access to those actions? If you try to give permission based on a tag but the resource does not support tags does the iam policy simply ignore the tag restriction instead of denying the action because the restriction cannot be met?

Comment: @luk2302  yes accroding the orignal policy in OP, it will allow all the actions. If you take a look the doc I attached and look under the `Authorization based on tags` on  `route53` it  says no, but in the policy everything is allowed so it will let that pass. I spent hours with AWS support team for this.

Comment: Yes, route53 does not support authorization based on tags but I would then expect IAM to always deny any route53 interactions because the `"StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/env": "qa"}` will not be true ever, similar to if I wrote `"StringEquals": {"nonesense": "yes"}`. I would **not** expect IAM to look at the statement, check if the statement "makes sense" for the current service and then ignore the statement if it does not.

Comment: @luk2302 my take away from the call with. AWS support was to look under that docs for tag-based restrictions. I am not sure things changed post that.

Comment: Doesn't apply to my situation, but I'll definitely keep this in mind - sounds like a terrible thing to find out by experience. Many thanks.

Comment: @luk2302 this is not the case now and it works as expected.

Comment: @rath it is denying access now, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Good to hear :) was about to try it out myself but you beat me to it apparently...